# Navigation between fragments java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android-fragments

i have a navigation drawer and 2 fragments, by default 1 of the fragment its shown and load a list, i want to change the fragment when the user select any object of the list but i have no idea how to change the fragment, i made a method inside the drawer and calle it when a object its selected but i get java.lang.IllegalStateException, here its the code

Main drawer:

```
public class DrawerPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentoPrincipalUsuario.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //cargar fragment principal usuario




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //fragmento del chofer




            Fragment fragmento= null;
            fragmento = new FragmentoPrincipalChofer();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                    .commit();




    }

    public void cambiarFragmento(){
        Fragment fragmento;
        fragmento = new PruebaUsuario();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pantalla_principal_usuario, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.cuenta) {

            Fragment fragmento= null;
            fragmento = new OpcionDrawerUsuario();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.historial_viajes) {
            Fragment fragmento= null;
            fragmento = new FragmentoViajesAcumulados();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                    .commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.contacto) {
            String emailAdress[] = {"gastondelacruz@gmail.com"};
            Intent email= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailAdress);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Pon aqui el motivo de tu mail");
            email.setType("text/plain");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Su mensaje");
            startActivity(email);


        } else if (id == R.id.compartir) {
            String texto="https://www.google.com.ar/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9JuBVvmcGanX8gejsK_4CA&gws_rd=ssl";
            Intent intento= new Intent();
            intento.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intento.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
            intento.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intento);

        } else if (id == R.id.version) {
            String prueba="aceptar";
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("prueba") //
                    .setMessage("Esta es una prueba todavia no poseo el numero de version del producto") //
                    .setPositiveButton(prueba, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }); //

            builder.show();

        } else if (id == R.id.salir) {

            finish();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


}
```

drawer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DrawerPrincipal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer_principal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when a object its selected i called the method from the fragment like the following:

```
DrawerPrincipal prueba=new DrawerPrincipal();
                prueba.cambiarFragmento();
```

Comment: please show your fragment + listadapter

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but i'll respond anyway..

It's not immediately obvious what's wrong.  Might be helpful if you posted the stack trace of the IllegalStateException.

Things to check:
make sure you're not mixing support fragments/activities with their alternate versions.

Also, you mention navigating from a drawer but the code is adding buttons to the action bar menu.  Not sure if this is what you're going for but those are different ui components.